# Access Denied on Subsite set to anonymous access on Claim based sp2010 web application

Tags: claims-based-auth, anonymous-authentication

I have a claims enabled sharepoint 2010 web application and set to anonymous access for entire site in central admin.
Site collection is NOT set to anonymous access. I have created a subsite with unique permission and provide anonymous access to the subsite.
But claim authenticated users coulnd access the subsite pages. I am getting sharepoint access denied page.

IIS web.config entries:
﻿authentication mode forms 
identity impersonate = true 
allow users ="*"

All IIS Authentication settings are enabled except Digest and Basic.

Note:
I had the same access denied issue if I create a application page inheriting from unsecuredpagelayoutbase and anonoymous authentication set to true as well.

Any help?

Thanks 
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the site while you are running Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/). If the site is referencing any outside content ( .jpg etc ) it needs to authenticate which brakes your login procedure.

In almost every anonymous troubleshooting I have ever participated in, this was the culprit.

It should be pretty clear in the main screen of the Fiddler program.